# How to Iterate over pages in Ebay

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am building a scraper for Ebay. I am trying to figure out a way to manipulate the page number portion of the Ebay url to go to the next page until there are no more pages (If you were on page 2 the page number portion would look like "_pgn=2"). I noticed that if you put any number greater than the max number of pages a listing has, the page will reload to the last page, not give like a page doesn't exist error. (If a listing has 5 pages, then the last listing' page number url portion of _pgn=5 would rout to the same page if the page number url portion was _pgn=100). How can I implement a way to start at page one, get the html soup of the page, get the all relevant data I want from the soup, then load up the next page with the new page number and start the process again until there are not any new pages to scrape? I tried to get the number of results a listing has by using selenium xpath and math.ceil the quotient of number of results and 50 (default number of max listings per page) and use that quotient as my max_page, but I get errors saying the element doesn't exist even though it does. self.driver.findxpath('xpath').text. That 243 is what I am trying to get with the xpath.
[image: That 243 is what I am trying to get with xpath]

```
class EbayScraper(object):

def __init__(self, item, buying_type):
    self.base_url = "https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw="
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"chromedriver.exe")
    self.item = item
    self.buying_type = buying_type + "=1"
    self.url_seperator = "&_sop=12&rt=nc&LH_"
    self.url_seperator2 = "&_pgn="
    self.page_num = "1"

def getPageUrl(self):
    if self.buying_type == "Buy It Now=1":
        self.buying_type = "BIN=1"

    self.item = self.item.replace(" ", "+")

    url = self.base_url + self.item + self.url_seperator + self.buying_type + self.url_seperator2 + self.page_num
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def getInfo(self, soup):
    for listing in soup.find_all("li", {"class": "s-item"}):
        raw = listing.find_all("a", {"class": "s-item__link"})
        if raw:
            raw_price = listing.find_all("span", {"class": "s-item__price"})[0]
            raw_title = listing.find_all("h3", {"class": "s-item__title"})[0]
            raw_link = listing.find_all("a", {"class": "s-item__link"})[0]
            raw_condition = listing.find_all("span", {"class": "SECONDARY_INFO"})[0]
            condition = raw_condition.text
            price = float(raw_price.text[1:])
            title = raw_title.text
            link = raw_link['href']
            print(title)
            print(condition)
            print(price)
            if self.buying_type != "BIN=1":
                raw_time_left = listing.find_all("span", {"class": "s-item__time-left"})[0]
                time_left = raw_time_left.text[:-4]
                print(time_left)
            print(link)
            print('\n')



if __name__ == '__main__':
item = input("Item: ")
buying_type = input("Buying Type (e.g, 'Buy It Now' or 'Auction'): ")

instance = EbayScraper(item, buying_type)
page = instance.getPageUrl()
instance.getInfo(page)
```

Comment: Another way to accomplish this could be to do `listing.find_all('span', class_='BOLD')` and iterate through the results until you reach the # of returned results.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to iterate all pages and gather all results then your script needs to check if there is a `next` page after you visit the page

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class EbayScraper(object):

    def __init__(self, item, buying_type):
        ...
        self.currentPage = 1

    def get_url(self, page=1):
        if self.buying_type == "Buy It Now=1":
            self.buying_type = "BIN=1"

        self.item = self.item.replace(" ", "+")
        # _ipg=200 means that expect a 200 items per page
        return '{}{}{}{}{}{}&_ipg=200'.format(
            self.base_url, self.item, self.url_seperator, self.buying_type,
            self.url_seperator2, page
        )

    def page_has_next(self, soup):
        container = soup.find('ol', 'x-pagination__ol')
        currentPage = container.find('li', 'x-pagination__li--selected')
        next_sibling = currentPage.next_sibling
        if next_sibling is None:
            print(container)
        return next_sibling is not None

    def iterate_page(self):
        # this will loop if there are more pages otherwise end
        while True:
            page = instance.getPageUrl(self.currentPage)
            instance.getInfo(page)
            if self.page_has_next(page) is False:
                break
            else:
                self.currentPage += 1

    def getPageUrl(self, pageNum):
        url = self.get_url(pageNum)
        print('page: ', url)
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        return soup

    def getInfo(self, soup):
        ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    item = input("Item: ")
    buying_type = input("Buying Type (e.g, 'Buy It Now' or 'Auction'): ")

    instance = EbayScraper(item, buying_type)
    instance.iterate_page()
```

the important functions here are `page_has_next` and `iterate_page`

- `page_has_next` - a function that check if the pagination of the page has another `li` element next to the `selected` page. e.g `< 1 2 3 >` if we are on page 1 then it checks if there is 2 next -> something like this
- `iterate_page` - a function that loop until there is no `page_next`

also note that you don't need selenium for this unless you need to mimic user clicks or need a browser to navigate.

Comment: That seems to work thank you. Although I noticed with items that do not have 50 or more listings (i.e, only one page) then it breaks at the pageHasNext function at the currentPage = container.find('li', 'x-pagination__li--selected') line. Any way to have it work so that if there isn't a next page (.find returns NoneType object). I assume the lines after that currentPage = ... try and take care of that problem, but they seem to not be working?

Comment: @DiegoDelgado `.find` returns a None. I think the problems with the code I have is that it assumes that there is always `currentPage` so I think you just need to check it if its Not otherwise return `False`.

Comment: That worked. Right after container is initialized, I checked if its equal to none. If none then returned false and the program stopped and went to the other methods that dissect and organize the data